# How link a Spring boot app at existing docker container for database?

Tags: postgresql, docker, spring-boot, solr

I want to use my app from a docker container with anothers docker container, one for `postgres` and one for `solr`.

My docker compose is:

```
version: '3'
services:
    core:
        build: ./core
        ports:
            - "8081:8081"
        environment:
            - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production"
        links:
          - postgresdb
          - solrdb
    postgresdb:
        image: postgres:9.4
        container_name: postgres
        ports: 
            - "5432:5432"
        environment:
            - DB_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver
            - DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
            - DB_USERNAME=db
            - DB_PASSWORD=db
        networks:
            default:
    solrdb:
       image: solr:5.5
       container_name: solr
       ports:
            - "8983:8983"
       environment:
            - DB_URL=http://localhost:8984/solr
       networks:
            default:
networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: mynet
```

And already I have containers for `solr` and `postgres` created, just I want to use it. How I can do it?

Comment: Expose the ports and connect them, if they are running on the same machine.

Comment: Yes, run on the same machine. Can you give me an example of how I can connect?

Answer (score 0):

You have already exposed the ports for solrdb and the postgresdb. So in your other container access these Dbs by the container names and the exposed port.

For example, solrDb should be accessed via solrdb:8983 and

the postgresdb should be accessed via postgresdb:5432

Edit :
Make sure that both the containers are operating in the same network. You need to add this network field for all the containers.

```
postgresdb:
    image: postgres:9.4
    container_name: postgresdb
    ports: 
        - "5432:5432"
    environment:
        - DB_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver
        - DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
        - DB_USERNAME=db
        - DB_PASSWORD=db
    networks:
      default:
```

and in the end of all the docker file

```
networks:
 default:
  external:
    name: <your-network-name>
```

And make sure that your predefined network is running prior to the start of these containers.
To create the network :

```
docker network create --driver overlay --scope global <your-network-name>
```

Note : Your container ('postgresdb') will be accessible by postgresdb:5432

Comment: I added in application.yml at `datasource` `url : 0.0.0.0:5432` and `postgres:5432` for postgres and `host: 0.0.0.0:8983` and `solr:8983` for solr, but doesn't work. And I'm not very sure I understand 100% what you want to say.

Comment: Still, doesn't work. I updated my question with new `docker-compose`. The error is: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused`. And this created new container and I want to use created containers.

Comment: You should use postgresdb:5432 to connect

Comment: But in my default application runned from Intellj works. I used the same containers. And I want to used same containers when I run with docker compose.